# A closed smooth manifold cannot admit free involutions if it does not bound.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have seen the following statement: If a closed smooth manifold does not bound, then it cannot admit fixed point free involutions. Here a manifold $M$ bound means there exists a compact manifold $W^{n+1}$ such that $\partial W=M$. I am considering unoriented cobordism.

By using Euler characteristic and fundamental groups I can determine when there is free involution for some surfaces but not getting the idea.

I would like to see proof of the above statement. I am unable to prove it.

Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: Much is missing in this question, for instance, that a "free involution" is a "fixed-point free involution", what do you mean by "bound" (you should specify which cobordism theory you have in mind, nonoriented?). Also, what are your thoughts? For instance, can you prove this claim for surfaces?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have edted my question.

Comment: OK, now it is a good question. I will write an answer when I have time. In brief: if $M\to M/\tau$ is the covering map of your involution, take its mapping cylinder. It will be the manifold $W$ such that $\partial W=M$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you please explain a little bit why $M$ will be the boundary of the mapping cylinder? My doubt is why $M\coprod M/{\tau} $ is not the boundary?

Comment: Because each point $x\in M/\tau$ is the image of two points $y_1, y_2\in M$ under the projection map. Accordingly,  a neighborhood of $x$ is the union of two neighborhoods of $y_1, y_2$ in $M\times [0,1]$, each homeomorphic to the closed half-space. Together, these two neighborhoods yield a neighborhood homeomorphic to $R^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be a closed $n$-dimensional manifold and $\tau: M\to M$ a fixed-point free involution. My argument works in any of the standard categories: topological, PL or smooth. Since you are asking about differentiable manifolds, I will work in the smooth category.

Define the quotient manifold $N=M/\tau$. Let $W\to N$ denote the interval bundle associated with the covering map $M\to N$. One way to define it is as the mapping cylinder of the projection $M\to N$. Alternatively, one can define it as follows: Consider the product manifold $E=M\times [-1,1]$. The group ${\mathbb Z}_2$ acts on  $M\times [-1,1]$: The action on $M$ is generated by the involution $\tau$, the action on the interval $[-1,1]$ is generated by the involution $t\mapsto -t$. This action on $E$ is free and, hence, we get the (compact) quotient-manifold with boundary $W=E/{\mathbb Z}_2$. The manifold $M$ projects diffeomorphically to the boundary of $W$, $M\cong \partial W$ and, hence, $M$ bounds.